# Iphone App with google maps + UIView does not respond to swipe gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiview

I've created a test project, it has a UIViewController. a UIView (myView) declared as xib it has an image and 3 buttons

I'm adding the UIView programmatically to UIViewController and add a swipe gesture to UIView in the `viewDidLoad` method of UIViewController

```
swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeAction:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[myView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

**All works well.**

Then I add the google maps to the UIViewcontroller again in `viewDidLoad`

```
   // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
```

**first problem:** myview is not showing --> I move the code of adding UIView to `viewDidAppear`.

now the view is seen the buttons respond **but the swipe gesture is not working**

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view, in which you added your `myView`, is getting replaced by your map view due to this line: `self.view = mapView_;` Hence, your view is not visible.

You should add your map view as a subview instead. Try replacing that line with `[self.view addSubview:mapView_]`

Comment: I haven't used `GMSMapView` but I believe adding it as a subview should be possible. You are passing `CGRectZero` as your frame while initializing  the map view, so maybe that is the reason it doesn't show up. Try giving a non-zero rect as your frame. If it still doesn't work try adding your `myView` after adding the `mapView_`